# How to draw both stroked and filled text in drawLayer:inContext delegate

Tags: cocoa, calayer, core-text

this is my **drawLayer** method in a **CALayer**'s delegate.

it's only responsible for drawing a `string with length = 1`.

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx 
    {
        CGRect boundingBox = CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(ctx);
        NSAttributedString *string = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.letter attributes:[self attrs]];

        CGContextSaveGState(ctx);

        CGContextSetShadowWithColor(ctx, CGSizeZero, 3.0, CGColorCreateGenericRGB(1.0, 1.0, 0.922, 1.0));
        CTLineRef line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)string);
        CGRect rect = CTLineGetImageBounds(line, ctx);
        CGFloat xOffset = CGRectGetMidX(rect);
        CGFloat yOffset = CGRectGetMidY(rect);
        CGPoint pos = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(boundingBox) - xOffset, CGRectGetMidY(boundingBox)- yOffset);
        CGContextSetTextPosition(ctx, pos.x, pos.y);

        CTLineDraw(line, ctx);

    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
}
```

here's the attributes dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
[NSFont fontWithName:@"GillSans-Bold" size:72.0], NSFontAttributeName,
[NSColor blackColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], NSStrokeWidthAttributeName,
[NSColor blackColor], NSStrokeColorAttributeName,
style, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, nil];
```

as is, the stroke does not draw, but the fill does.

if i comment out the stroke attributes in the dictionary, the fill draws.

i know this can't be right, but i can't find any reference to this problem.

is this a known issue when drawing text with a delegate ?

as the string is one character, i was following the doc example not using any **framesetter** machinery, but tried that anyway as a fix attempt without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467597/how-do-you-stroke-the-outside-of-an-nsattributedstring) question's answer, i realized that i needed to be using a `negative number` for the stroke value. i was thinking of the stroke being applied to the **outside** of the letter drawn by `CTLineDraw`, rather then inside the text shape.

i'm answering my own question, in case this should help anyone else with this misunderstanding, as i didn't see the [referenced doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1531/_index.html) covering this.

Comment: This negative number comment really helped me. Thank you a ton