# iPhone SDK: How to add an outline to UILabel's text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, label

I was wondering if there was a way to add an outline to a piece of text like a `UILabel`.

How can I make this happen? I've tried `text.layer.borderWidth` but that only creates a box around the label frame. I want the outline to be around the individual characters in the label.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at those two posts, I think they could help you:

[How do I make UILabel display outlined text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103148/how-do-i-make-uilabel-display-outlined-text)

[How do you stroke the *outside* of an NSAttributedString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467597/how-do-you-stroke-the-outside-of-an-nsattributedstring)