# Adding a stroke to a UILabel text in SWIFT

Tags: swift, nsstring

I am trying to add a stroke to a UILabel text in Swift. This is the text I have used:

```
var congratsLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, popUpView.frame.size.height * 0.540, popUpView.frame.size.width, 70))
congratsLabel.font = UIFont(name: Font.Daydreamer, size: 70)
congratsLabel.text = "Snap!"
congratsLabel.numberOfLines = 0
congratsLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
congratsLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
popUpView.addSubview(congratsLabel)
```

I have also tried using the `NSMutableAttributedString` althoough it is coming out a bit ropey and not how I want, the code I used for that also was:

```
var String = "Snap!"

var strokeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: Font.Daydreamer, size: 70.0)!])
strokeString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.whiteColor(), range: NSRange(location:0,length:5))
strokeString.addAttribute(NSStrokeColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.blackColor(), range:  NSRange(location: 0, length: 5))
strokeString.addAttribute(NSStrokeWidthAttributeName, value: 1, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 5))
```

This is the look I am trying to recreate.

[image]

But it is coming out like this (The backgrounds are different) but as you can see the stroke is taking over the entire word:

[image]

Comment: Could you show what's your current render? You should use the `NSAttributedString` version. But we can't guess from your code what's wrong.

Comment: I have edited. The problem is that the stroke is suffocating the entire word leaving no room for the actual word in the middle

Comment: Try to put first a negative value to `NSStrokeWidthAttributeName` value. Like -1 (and try to find the correct value: -2, -3, etc.).

Comment: No that still doesn't work, same outcome...?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467597/how-do-you-stroke-the-outside-of-an-nsattributedstring

Comment: @HenryBrown Larme is right. A negative stroke will enable _both_ stroke & fill (where a positive value only a stroke and a transparent fill - that's why it is not visible in your example). I have just tried it with a couple of fonts in a playground and works fine...

Comment: And regarding your comment (the stroke is suffocating the entire word...), that's right... maybe a two-step solution like a slightly bigger copy with a large black stroke behind the text could achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. It was actually your idea @Alladinian with putting a layer behind the text that has the best result. Thanka!