# Getting issue on strokeWidth NSAttributedString in iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, ios14, nsmutablestring

I have an issue with stroke color on iOS 14.

```
let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
    .foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
    .strokeColor: UIColor.black,
    .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 65, weight: .black),
    .strokeWidth: -1 
]
lableNumber.attributedText =  NSAttributedString(string: "2", attributes: attributes)
```

iOS 13

[image]

iOS 14

[image: example]

It is working on iOS 13 but not working in iOS 14. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: the issue is not displaying properly "2" in iOS14.

Comment: weird "star" pattern is the issue here

Answer (score 4):

Looks like Apple has changed the font outlines in iOS 14, the glyphs for 6 and 9 exhibit similar artifacts. I would file a bug with Apple.

Depending on your requirements, using `UIFont.monospacedSystemFont(...)` could work, those glyphs still look OK to me. (Edit: "1" has artifacts in the monospaced version as well. Maybe use `UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 65)` instead?)

Comment: I've filed the bug for you. FB8795082

Comment: Actually, I have to print "1" to "20" in my app. I have tried with your way "UIFont.monospacedSystemFont(...)", So, "2" is displaying properly but "1" is not displayed properly.

Comment: @vikasprajapati The only workaround I can think of for now is to use some other font entirely. For example, Avenir looks okay. Play around until you find a font you're satisfied with.

Comment: @matt sure, I will try with another font.

Comment: @matt yes, "6", "9" also

Comment: `HelveticaNeue-Bold` also looks OK to me - updated my answer

Comment: @matt can you please give me any link for this bug FB8795082?

Comment: This is still an issue with iOS 15 beta 1. It affects 269ABKMNPQXaeky#$^&*+<>. I filed a bug report 9/11/20 but no response from Apple yet...